# 1950-60's movie about alien that crashes to Earth and loses its hand which proceeds to attack people

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

Does anyone know about an old movie (I think it's black & white) in which an alien that crashes to Earth loses its hand. The thought has occurred to me that this may not be a movie, but a TV show episode.

The hand then crawls away from the crash site to become a stow-away in a woman's car. The alien's hand is cut just above the wrist and veins or tendons trail from it as it crawls. It has thin fingers. The setting is the daytime when it gets into the woman's car. When she gets home, the hand crawls into the house and hides in the closet where it crawls up to the top shelf and then jumps on the woman when she opens the door and strangles her. I think it goes on to hurt more people.

It is not the movie title, *The Hand*.

Comment: This does sound familiar. I recall it as a B&W movie or TV show. From what I remember the hand is in the back seat of her car. And it starts climbing up the back of her seat. Just as it reaches the top, ready to grab her, she either hits a bump and it falls back, or she arrives at her destination and gets out just in time. BUT I dont know if it was necessarily an Alien hand, maybe just a zombie hand or cursed hand. It look like a normal human-ish hand, as opposed to someone wearing an Alien looking glove prop.

Answer (score 7):

Is it possible you're thinking of *[The Crawling Hand](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/TheCrawlingHand)*?

> Astronauts keep going crazy and blowing up on their way back to the ground, and scientists can't figure out why. The latest astronaut to fall to this mysterious syndrome manages to contact his scientist superiors just before doing himself in; he alternates between pleas to "push the red" Self-Destruct Mechanism and violent urges to "Kill! Kill!" Finally the "red" is pushed, the astronaut is blown to shards and the scientists are still stumped.
>
> Meanwhile, over in California, young med student Paul frolicks on the beach with his girlfriend when they happen upon the severed arm of the dead astronaut. Against his girl's wishes, Paul returns to the beach and takes the arm home with him (for what reason, we're not told). Soon, it becomes apparent to everyone (in the audience, at least) that whatever malediction had possessed the astronaut still possesses the arm, which promptly goes on a killing spree (said spree resulting in a grand total of ONE death). Paul himself is a prime suspect in the murder, but the two scientists arrive with their own theories. Then the mysterious murderous force begins to infect Paul as well, and he attacks a Malt Shop owner and his own girlfriend. After realizing what he's doing, Paul takes the hand out to a junkyard with the intent of destroying it, and between a fever of over 100 and some hungry cats, the evil is defeated... er, handily.

It's not an actual alien, but I think it otherwise matches.

Comment: If this is correct, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: The Crawling Hand is not the movie I'm thinking of. The hand is from an alien that crashes to earth. Thanks for answering, though.

Comment: No worries. Incidentally, thank you very much for commenting on the answers. It's classy, and it helps us narrow down the answers by your reactions.

Comment: Thanks for adding the video clip. It is surprisingly similar in story-line, but I still don't think this is it. The alien's hand is cut just above the wrist and veins or tendons trail from it as it crawls. It has thin fingers. The setting is the daytime when it gets into the woman's car. Honestly, I'm not sure if it was a full film or a TV show. The movie has kept with me for many years and I wish I had noted the title. Thanks all!

Answer (score 6):

#### [*Invasion of the Hell Creatures*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050545/?ref_=tt_urv) (also known as *Invasion of the Saucer Men*) (1957)

A lot of the reviews on IMDb mention the aliens can detach their hands which attack people, for example:

> In this one, a young couple accidentally run over an alien but its hand comes alive and terrorises people. The local farmer doesn't like the teenagers using his land for snogging in their cars. More aliens then appear and kill one of the teens with an overdose of alcohol as revenge for their mate being killed. A flying saucer then blows up with the military in attendance and the aliens are done away with at the end by light, their weakness. With a drunken bull.

> Edward L. Cahn directed this cult classic about a pair of teenagers on a date who accidentally run over a newly arrived alien. Strangely, its hand falls off and comes to life on its own. Meanwhile, drunken friend Joe(played amusingly by Frank Gorshin) takes one home, but is injected by an alien with a fatal overdose of alcohol, and the authorities don't believe the teenagers' story of alien invaders.

> I saw this movie in the early '60s, when I saw about 6 or 7. I have never been able to forget that severed hand, with the needles coming out of the fingertips, as it crawled up the car seat toward the unsuspecting teens.

The aliens look like the below:

[image: Aliens from the film crash land]

It is available in full on YouTube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msI1CS215Q4).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and taking the time to edit my question.I guess I have to be more careful. The movie you suggested isn't the one I'm looking for, however; it was set in the daytime and I don't think it was run over by a car. I think it got severed in the crash and somehow it got into the car of the woman and crawled up the back of her seat to try to get her. I found that scene very creepy. After failing to get her the first time, it then found its way into her closet and then strangled her (or attempted to). I really like the movie you suggested, though.

Comment: Just to check, the 1965 remake, *Attack of the Eye Creatures*, also doesn't match up? https://youtu.be/IotkzActVdA?t=1364

Comment: No, sadly, it does not. This one is in color and also set at night. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I too remembered a crawling hand with needles that came out of the fingers (which is about all I remember).

- However, I just watched a youtube video with all the scenes of the crawling hand from the movie of the same name (The Crawling Hand, 1963) and it has the scene of the hand on the top shelf of the closet jumping down to strangle the woman. It is the severed hand of an astronaut whose spacecraft is blown up.
- Apparently, The Invasion of the Saucer-men (1957) is the movie with the crawling hand (severed from an alien) that has the needles coming out of the fingers.