# Old BW sci-fi movie pumpkin-headed aliens with eyes on the back of their hands

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, tv

I don't recall if I even remember this movie correctly, but here goes. About 50 years ago I saw a BW sci-fi flick on TV. It had sorta pumpkin headed aliens in it who had landed on Earth. Their eyes were on the back of their hands. One of the hands gets severed and it crawls thru the forest in the leaves, or maybe it was along the side of a road. I can't recall exactly. That's pretty much the only scene I recall from the movie since it was my 10-year-old brain watching it.

So, did I make this up or is it an actual alien sci-fi B movie from the early 60s or late 50s?

Comment: https://static.tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pub/images/Pale_Man_883.jpg

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for a good story-id question; they might prompt some more memories for you to [edit] into your question.  Where were you when you saw this?

Comment: Duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/204485/4804

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is [Invasion of the Saucermen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_of_the_Saucer_Men), which features aliens with giant heads and a severed hand that crawls around killing people.

[image]

Comment: You are the best! So, it was indeed an actual movie. Thanks so much.

Comment: @MarkKendrick - [You're very welcome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ), and many thanks for the acceptance