# Martian movie where their hands became detached and would crawl to attack unsuspecting humans

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw an old bw Martian/alien movie as a young boy in the 60s where the Martian/aliens hands came off and would crawl; dragging the jagged wrist.  I remember one scene where the hand was climbing the backseat of the car seat to grab the unsuspecting driver.  Gave me nightmares.  Any ideas which late 50s or early 60s movie meets this "crawling hands" criteria?

Comment: Sounds similar to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/204485/1950-60s-movie-about-alien-that-crashes-to-earth-and-loses-its-hand-which-proce/204487#204487

Comment: Are you sure it was an alien? There's a number of horror movies from that time period featuring severed hands in general, but most don't feature aliens but some sort of supernatural or magic/curse.

Comment: Ohh. I'm pretty sure I would have remembered that one.

Answer (score 18):

Could be [**Invasion of the saucer-men**](https://johneaves.wordpress.com/2012/06/19/invasion-of-the-saucer-men-the-55th-anniversarry/)

[image]

["Hand" scene on youtube](https://youtu.be/la9VXiM8GJU?t=80)

> The couple jumps out of the car and more lightning flashes reveal a
> strange little body with a  huge head pined under the car. while the
> couple tries to figure things out,  **we see the creatures hand fall off
> and crawl over to the tire. The severed hand has an eyeball on top** of
> it’s veiny surface and as the eye is looking around sharp needles
> start to grow out of the finger tips…. next the hand dives at the tire
> and pops it from under the car…

Comment: If this is the right answer, please be sure to click on the tick/checkmark to the left to indicate that.